# Issues running first application in Android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-emulator

I have recently started looking into Android development. When I try running my first application in an Emulator I get the following message in the console in Eclipse.

"[2014-08-07 23:57:12 - edfsdfs] Starting activity com.example.edfsdfs.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

[2014-08-07 23:57:12 - edfsdfs] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.

[2014-08-07 23:57:13 - edfsdfs] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.edfsdfs/.MainActivity }"

Can anyone please advise? I don't think it's an issue the the code but a Emulator issue.

Many Thanks

Comment: Does the emulator stall? other than the warning , are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: It doesn't show any other error messages except on the emulator that that says the program has stopped responding.

Comment: Please refer to this question here....   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837532/security-warning-on-libdvm-so-noticed-while-deploying-android-apps