# My android emulator isnt working

Tags: android, compiler-errors, emulation

When i load my app on the android emulator, the console tels me that everythig is running normaly. but the after a minnute I get this error: 
"[2014-09-19 20:59:27 - test] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix."
The proses stops and nothing more happens. If I try to run an earlier verson of the app that is stil on the emulator it ses: "Unfortunaly, Test(witch is the name of my app) has stoped. Please help, Iv been stuck with this problem for over a week now. This is the mesenges I get in my console:

```
[2014-09-21 10:24:54 - test] ------------------------------
[2014-09-21 10:24:54 - test] Android Launch!
[2014-09-21 10:24:54 - test] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-21 10:24:54 - test] Performing com.example.test.Splash activity launch
[2014-09-21 10:24:55 - test] Uploading test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-21 10:24:55 - test] Installing test.apk...
[2014-09-21 10:25:06 - test] Success!
[2014-09-21 10:25:06 - test] Starting activity com.example.test.Splash on device emulator-5554
[2014-09-21 10:25:09 - test] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21837532/1518921 ?

Comment: Known bug.  Ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using genymotion as your emulator ?  Its much more stable and faster than default android emulator.

http://www.genymotion.com/

Is your code working on real device ?

Comment: I think it is rather a comment then an answer

Comment: Thanks, Iv not tryed running on an real device eather cause I have the same problem with the deafault "Hello World" Program

Comment: Can you please update you fist post with activity code and manifest   ? Also logcat would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the old version of the app and push again. This was provided as one of the answers here: [Security warning on libdvm.so noticed while deploying Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21837532/1518921) .