# libtinyWRAP_neon.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using Native Library in my appliation, but when i run my app without exporting its apk then it works fine. But after exporting the apk it's getting crash the application with the error message

**libtinyWRAP_neon.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.**

I have searched it but not found answer to resolve it. I am using minSdk-8 and maxSdk-17 with Android 4.4

So I don't know how to fix it. Any Suggestion will be appreciated..........**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

recompile the library with latest NDK available.

ref : [Security warning on libdvm.so noticed while deploying Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837532/security-warning-on-libdvm-so-noticed-while-deploying-android-apps)

Comment: Thanks Kirtan, let me try this.