# Error while uploading dependencies.apk : WARNING: linker: libhoudini.so has text relocations

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2.3 stable in Windows and while creating any new project and installing apk on emulator, I am getting this error and apk install fails.

> Error while uploading dependencies.apk : WARNING: linker: libhoudini.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix

How Can I solve the problem?

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577315/warning-linker-app-process-has-text-relocations-this-is-wasting-memory-and-is

Comment: no. It occurs when I started using AS 2.3, with 2.2.3 there is no problem

Comment: are you compiling `libhoudini.so` yourself?

Comment: no. @nandsito And how can I find  libhoudini.so file in project directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research, I found out that  gradle 2.3.0 plugin has issue with ARM translator which I installed in my Genymotion emulator. And libhoudini.so is a proprietary ARM translation layer of emulator. That's why my installation of apk through Android Studio was failed with emulator. So, emulators without GApps  will work.

Comment: I started having this issue after upgrading gradle to 3.3, tired everything including deleting my emulator and re-installing it back. But to no avail. Sometimes the suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444980/android-install-on-device-failure-install-canceled-by-user/29742394#29742394 provides a temporary fix. How you come across a more permanent fix?

Comment: edit  build.gradle file to version 2.2.3 in  with Android Studio 2.3 until the issue is fixed

Answer (score 19):

After trying to options given in this post and failure to get app installed. This problem is caused after updating Android Studio to Version 2.3 and Gradle to 3.3 (I have actually latest 3.4.1 so problem is not with Gradle version).
I tried to disable **"Instant Run"** Feature of android studio and installation works like charm.

So go to

**File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment> Instant Run**

And then disable it. After that you will get working installation in GenyMotion as well.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it for me as well. Why is the Android development stack such a mess?

Comment: Android Studio is not one of the best IDE. They are not developing it from scratch, just reusing Java Intellij as base that was designed for Java and not purely for Android.

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with this issue for almost 27 hours. I found out that after updating my android studio and gradle it prompts you to enabling instant run on your projects. Therefore don't enabling instant run when prompted by android studio. As this results in the issue. There known bug instant Run bug on genymotion. Refer to [Issue 233845:  Instant Run could work on genymotion](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233845&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Sta) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem occurs using Genymotion, Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle 3.3. For now, my temporary workaround is use an emulator created by the AVD Manager and not Genymotion.