# How can i fix libhoudini.so has text relocations

Tags: android

```
"Error while uploading dependencies.apk : WARNING: linker: 
libhoudini.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and 
prevents security hardening. Please fix."
```

I am beginner learning android.
I have to use **ARM EABI v7a**, then standard android emulator slowly, so I used **Genymotion** emulator.
When i running my android app. A issue mentioned above occured.
I use android studio 2.3.
build.gradle:2.3.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while uploading dependencies.apk : WARNING: linker: libhoudini.so has text relocations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585924/error-while-uploading-dependencies-apk-warning-linker-libhoudini-so-has-text)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable "Instant Run" Feature of android studio and installation works like charm.

So go to

**File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment> Instant Run**

And then disable it. After that you will get working installation in GenyMotion as well.

Cheers!!!