# WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix

Tags: android

I am writing this android app and all of a suddenly it now doesn't launch. Well, it does but then say:

> [Your app] has closed unexpectedly

The strange thing is that it shows no error messages in logcat.The only messager that I saw is this:

```
WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a      security risk. Please fix.
```

So I did some searching and came across this:

[mylib.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141538/mylib-so-has-text-relocations-this-is-wasting-memory-and-is-a-security-risk-pl)

but that was talking about the NDK, which I'm not using. So I have no idea what this error message means, nor what `lbvc1dec_sa.ca7.so` is. So how can I fix this? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This work for me: 
modify build.gradle script to a lower version due to the android studio you are working with

initial:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.imageloadingdemo"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

after:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.imageloadingdemo"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason can be minimum sdk version your app uses is greater than os sdk version of your device.

So keep your application's minimum sdk version less than or equal os sdk version of your device.

Answer (score 0):

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: lenovo-lenovo_a328-L7DEKZVWS8QSLV9T
Uploading file

    local path: 

C:\Users\vishal\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
========================================================================

    remote path: 

/data/local/tmp/com.example.vishal.myapplication
------------------------------------------------

Installing com.example.vishal.myapplication

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.vishal.myapplication"

WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.

WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.

pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.vishal.myapplication Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

I faced the same problem but finally I go the solution which work for me after change

`pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.vishal.myapplicationpath` of my project from  `C:\Users\vishal\AndroidStudioProjects` to  `F:\drive`

so it runs finally.