# Get Native Lib from data for Android System App

Tags: java, android, java.library.path, android-native-library

I want to get the native lib path from data for my app that will be installed in the system, I have tried this code:

```
String libPath = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/lib/" + libName+".so";
System.load(libPath);
```

But it gives this error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
>   /data/data/xxxx/lib/lib.so not found

I tried to not hardcod it using

```
String libraryPath = context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/lib/"+libname+".so";
System.load(libraryPath);
```

but the same error was shown, if I use this code :

```
String libPath = context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir +libname+".so";
System.load(libPath);
```

The app will try to get native lib from system/app and the same error is shown, Can anybody help to force get native lib from data? Maybe something like this

> context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir

But force to data, not system, because when I try to show that libpath in log (when I try installed in data), it will show

> /data/app/apppackage-1/lib/arm/libname.so

There is a number after package name sometimes -1, sometimes -2.

Comment: Seems your target SDK is 23 . Please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845956/android-m-crash-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed/32846340#32846340 , It will solve your issue

Comment: Try this String libPath = context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir +File.separator +libname+".so";

Comment: that's not worked, I still got same error @dex

Comment: Could you solve your problem? My application has a library and is installed in the system/priv-app/ folder. And when you start, these libraries are in the /System/lib/ folder. Here is my question http://clc.am/0sZpqg