# Make ZBAR scanner compatible with Android 6.0 (API 23)

Tags: android, zbar

I am self-taught in Android, using Studio 2.1 and trying to get the app working on API version 23.

I am using ZBAR barcode scanner, to scan the barcodes of books and then do a lookup of the ISBN code.

This all works nicely in lower API versions.  When I get to 23 there is a documented change to how Android works with a particular component.

And here is the rub - I don't understand what I need to do to fix it.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: arw.apps.barcode, PID: 24533
                                                              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/arw.apps.barcode-1/lib/arm/libiconv.so: has text relocations
                                                                  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
                                                                  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                  at arw.apps.barcode.ZBarScannerActivity.<clinit>(ZBarScannerActivity.java:29)
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The app compiles right, and this happens when I try to activate the camera to perform the barcode scan.

I see the DLOpen Fail error, referring to text relocations.  I have read up that Android has been warning about this for a while, and in 6.0 its has not stopped working.

For good measure, I can confirm this code is present:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("iconv");
}
```

And this is in my .build file

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile files ('libs/zbar.jar')
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
```

What other artifacts can I post here to help you help me :-)

Grateful in advance for asistance

Alex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845956/android-m-crash-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed

Comment: Thanks for the reply Karen, but the example question you link to is about the dlopen failing due to not finding the file.  my issue is about the file being unsupported I think?