# NDK12b: Different ELF produced by clang vs gcc using the standalone toolchain and the same build scripts

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, ndk-build

Our product contains multiple source packages. Some of the source packages are built using autotool/conf.

Based on what google said of switching to clang as a default compiler for the NDK starting with NDK-13, we went ahead with the switch in the *.mk files as well as in our env setup and build scripts. No make files where changed.

We were using NDK-10d which is old, so we switched to NDK-12b.  We also generated a standalone toolchain from it, as recommended by Android's documentation, to simplify our build scripts and standardize across all.

The issue I am facing is the crash on launch as soon as the native code is loaded. What I have noticed is a warning in logcat regarding: `unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe` (**VERNEED**) and `0x6fffffff` (**VERNEEDNUM**).

Then, the dreaded: `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x30 in tid 22246`.

The stack trace tells me very, very little:

```
08-11 15:31:02.421 128-128/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00036b8c  /system/lib/libc.so
08-11 15:31:02.421 128-128/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0003817b  /system/lib/libc.so (vfprintf+18)
08-11 15:31:02.421 128-128/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00035251  /system/lib/libc.so (fprintf+12)
08-11 15:31:02.421 128-128/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000015fd  /data/app/com.myapp.demo-1/lib/arm/libappdebug.so (pipe_listen+328)
08-11 15:31:02.421 128-128/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0001659b  /system/lib/libc.so
08-11 15:31:02.421 128-128/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000144c3  /system/lib/libc.so
```

Notice that comparing the data within the ELFs as dumped by `readelf -d` shows the absence of those 2 DT entries in the binaries generated by *arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.9* builds.

Any ideas, pointers, ...anything at all ..., would be much appreciated cuz i have been stuck for (blush) 3 days now.

Thanks.

Comment: It would have helped if you had shown the difference of output from `readelf -d` for the two versions...

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the problem of your `unused DT entry`. If you're using your library to pipe stuff somewhere else, that warning will appear at every run and endanger your pipe to receive garbage, or your app to receive excpetions. Please have a look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41900551/1147688).