# Why does LTO introduce new DT flags TLSDESC_PLT and TLSDESC_GOT in armv8a NDK build

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, arm, elf

I'm building an armv8a SDK for Android using the NDK and I wanted to build with LTO enabled. I added `-flto` to the compile and link flags for the C++ toolchain, and all went well, until I tried to run in the emulator, at which point an error like the following was emitted:

`WARNING: linker: /data/lib/libservice.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffef6 arg 0x8e30`

and

`WARNING: linker: /data/lib/libservice.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffef7 arg 0x2fb50`

Some research led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206409/unused-dt-entry-type-0x1d-arg?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which allowed me to dig out the symbol names for `0x6ffffef6` and `0x6ffffef6`, they happen to be `TLSDESC_PLT` and `TLSDESC_GOT` respectively, so clearly something to do with dynamic linker and the PLT/GOT, and also with TLS. Fine.

Comparing the non LTO build with the LTO build, these flags definitely only come in for the LTO build:

`$ readelf -a /lto/lib/libservice.so | grep TLS
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  TLS            0x000000000001ed70 0x000000000002ed70 0x000000000002ed70
 0x000000006ffffef6 (TLSDESC_PLT)        0x8e30
 0x000000006ffffef7 (TLSDESC_GOT)        0x2fb50
00000002ffd8  000000000407 R_AARCH64_TLSDESC                    0
00000002ffe8  000000000407 R_AARCH64_TLSDESC                    8
   579: 0000000000000008     8 TLS     LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 _ZN5xxxxx12_GLOBAL__N_113
   788: 0000000000000000     1 TLS     LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 __tls_guard
$`

`$ readelf -a /nolto/lib/libservice.so | grep TLS
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
$`

So, some questions:

- Why does the android armv8a runtime reject these DT flags?
- Why does enabling LTO seem to change the TLS implementation or needs? Why do these tags get emitted (along with the other symbols)?
- How can I prevent that, or otherwise avoid this issue? Can I request some other TLS model?
- I've found at least one other issue like this, where the Android environment rejects the flag `DT_ORIGIN` which is usually required for `$ORIGIN` processing, but still honors `$ORIGIN` even without `DT_ORIGIN` set. Is the rejection of the `TLDESC_` flags potentially a similarly overzealous check, and the code is in fact fine, which would indicate an NDK bug?

Any insights appreciated. Note that this seems to work for other Android targets, specifically the Android x86_64 build worked just fine with `-flto`, and the resulting binaries do not have any `TLSDESC` anything in the `readelf -a` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to NDK r18 beta2, and I no longer have this problem. It appears that the underlying bug was something to do with not propagating the use of emulated TLS down through the gold linker plugin (see https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/498), which was fixed in r18.