# Error wasting memory android studio

Tags: android-studio

```
06/29 13:42:08: Launching app
$ adb push D:\ProjectAndroid\Wee\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.greenfrog.wee
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.greenfrog.wee"
```

WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.greenfrog.wee
Success

how to fix this issue?

Comment: You may want to look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141538/mylib-so-has-text-relocations-this-is-wasting-memory-and-is-a-security-risk-pl)

Comment: Yes, i have been look that post for several time. it last 2 week and iritate me. i am newbie and still when create hello word, it show an error.

Comment: This has popped up for me over the last few days as well. Are you using a kitkat emulator?

Comment: Yes, i use Kitkat emulator(Galaxy Nexus API 19)
and after that warning, it show error like below:


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.greenfrog.wee/com.example.greenfrog.wee.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.greenfrog.wee/com.example.greenfrog.wee.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity